# Stream not rebuilding the widget

Tags: flutter, dart, stream, bloc, dart-async

I'm trying to put a very simple project together. Aim here is to fetch some data from the HackerNews API and show it to the user. The code was working perfectly until I introduced the functionality to fetch each item from the top_ids list. I tried debugging it and I don't see any error whatsoever. However, I'm still not getting the required output (which is to fetch each item from the top_ids list)

**news_list_screen**

```
Widget buildList(StoriesBloc storiesBloc) {
    return StreamBuilder(
      stream: storiesBloc.topIds,
      builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot<List<int>> snapshot) {
        if (!snapshot.hasData) {
          return Center(
            child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
          );
        }
        return ListView.builder(
          itemCount: snapshot.data!.length,
          itemBuilder: (context, int index) {
            storiesBloc.fetchItem(snapshot.data![index]);
            return NewsListTile(
              itemId: snapshot.data![index],
            );
          },
        );
      },
    );
  }
}

class NewsListTile extends StatelessWidget {
  final int itemId;
  NewsListTile({required this.itemId});
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final bloc = StoriesBlocProvider.of(context);
    return StreamBuilder(
      stream: bloc.items,
      builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot<Map<int, Future<ItemModel>>> snapshot) {
        if (!snapshot.hasData) {
          return Text('Fetching item');
        }
        return FutureBuilder(
          future: snapshot.data![itemId],
          builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot<ItemModel> itemSnapshot) {
            if (!itemSnapshot.hasData) {
          //This gets populated with the correct ids
              return Text('Still loading item $itemId');
            }
            return Text(itemSnapshot.data!.title);
          },
        );
      },
    );
  }
}
```

**stories_bloc**

```
class StoriesBloc {
  final _newsRepository = NewsRepository();

  final _topIds = PublishSubject<List<int>>();
  final _itemsOutput = BehaviorSubject<Map<int, Future<ItemModel>>>();
  final _itemsFetcher = PublishSubject<int>();

  Stream<List<int>> get topIds => _topIds.stream;
  Stream<Map<int, Future<ItemModel>>> get items => _itemsOutput.stream;

  Function(int) get fetchItem => _itemsFetcher.sink.add;

  StoriesBloc() {
    _itemsFetcher.stream.transform(_itemsTransformer()).pipe(_itemsOutput);
  }

  fetchTopIds() async {
    final ids = await _newsRepository.fetchTopIds();
    _topIds.sink.add(ids);
  }

  _itemsTransformer() {
    return ScanStreamTransformer(
      (Map<int, Future<ItemModel>> cache, int id, index) {
        cache[id] = _newsRepository.fetchItem(id);
        return cache;
      },
      <int, Future<ItemModel>>{},
    );
  }

  dispose() {
    //code
  }
}
```

**news_repository**

```
class NewsRepository {
  List<Source> sources = <Source>[
    newsDbProvider,
    NewsApiProvider(),
  ];

  List<Cache> caches = <Cache>[
    newsDbProvider,
  ];

  Future<List<int>> fetchTopIds() async {
    late List<int> ids;
    Source source;

    for (source in sources) {
      ids = await source.fetchTopIds();
      if (ids.isNotEmpty) {
        break;
      }
    }

    return ids;
  }

  Future<ItemModel> fetchItem(int id) async {
    print('itemID to be fetched inside repo - $id');
    ItemModel? item;
    var source;
    Cache cache;

    for (source in sources) {
      item = await source.fetchItem(id);
      if (item != null) {
        break;
      }
    }

    for (cache in caches) {
      if (cache != source){
        cache.addItem(item!);
      } 
    }
    return item;
  }
}
```

**news_api_provider**

```
class NewsApiProvider implements Source {
  Client client = Client();

  Future<List<int>> fetchTopIds() async {
    final response = await client.get(Uri.parse('$_root/topstories.json'));
    final parsedJsonIds = json.decode(response.body);
    return parsedJsonIds.cast<int>();
  }

  Future<ItemModel> fetchItem(int id) async {
    print('Inside API provider. Tryna fetch $id');
    final response = await client.get(Uri.parse('$_root/item/$id.json'));
    print('Status Code' + response.statusCode.toString());
    print(response.body);
    final parsedJsonItem = json.decode(response.body);
    final itemModel = ItemModel.fromJson(parsedJsonItem);
    return itemModel;
  }
}
```

Now, the interesting part is that I do see "Still loading the item - itemID" on the screen but It never resolves, as If my FutureBuilder never receives any data. However, during the debugging I was able to see that my api is indeed working and even the cache map in the streamTransformer is getting populated as well.

I'm still unable to understand why the data is not flowing from the streamTransformer to my itemsOutput stream which is actually responsible for showing this data.

I'm trying so hard to get this working and have checked my code millions of times. I would really appreciate if you could help me resolve this. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Just a FYI, print statements written in between the code statements show the correct results.

Answer (score 1):

Okay. So it looks like - though the api is sending in some ids for the top posts but those ids do not exist when we fetch them through the api (using fetchItem method). Therefore the ItemModel was unable to work upon such requests which caused the error.

This is how I solved it ->

```
ItemModel.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> parsedJson)
      : id = parsedJson['id'] ?? 0,
        deleted = parsedJson['deleted'] ?? false,
        type = parsedJson['type'] ?? '',
        by = parsedJson['by'] ?? '',
        time = parsedJson['time'] ?? 0,
        text = parsedJson['text'] ?? '',
        dead = parsedJson['dead'] ?? false,
        parent = parsedJson['parent'] ?? 0,
        kids = parsedJson['kids'] ?? [],
        url = parsedJson['url'] ?? '',
        score = parsedJson['score'] ?? 0,
        title = parsedJson['title'] ?? 'Did not find',
        descendants = parsedJson['descendants'] ?? 0;
```